# Unable to execute GCM Android notification in production. It works on local machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-cloud-messaging

I'm unable to run GCM notification code in production. Though it is working on local server as expected.

```
    private void SendNotificationPresent()
    {
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            string query = "Select distinct MS.Std_Id,TSA.Cls_Id,TSA.Cls_Div_Id,MSC.Cls_Name,MCD.Div_Grade,TUL.User_GCM_Reg_Id,TUL.User_Id,TSA.Act_Remark,MIN(TSA.Act_Sch_Id),MS.Std_Fname+' '+MS.Std_Lname AS StudentName, Format(Getdate(), 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss')  as date FROM  Trn_Student_Act_Schedule TSA  Inner Join Mst_Students MS On MS.Std_Id=TSA.Std_Id Inner Join Trn_User_Login TUL On TUL.User_Id=MS.Parent_F_Id OR TUL.User_Id=MS.Parent_M_Id Inner Join Mst_School_Classes MSC on MSC.Cls_Id=TSA.Cls_Id  Inner Join Mst_Class_Division MCD ON MCD.Div_Id=TSA.Cls_Div_Id WHERE MS.STD_ID = '" + objlog.Std_Id + "'and TSA.Act_Remark='Present'  And TUL.User_GCM_Reg_Id<>''  and format(TSA.Date_From,'dd/MM/yyyy')= CONVERT(date,GETDATE()) Group by MS.Std_Id,TSA.Cls_Id,TSA.Cls_Div_Id,MSC.Cls_Name,MCD.Div_Grade,TUL.User_GCM_Reg_Id,TUL.User_Id,TSA.Act_Remark,MS.Std_Fname,MS.Std_Lname";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            con.Close();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            da.Fill(dt);

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow dtRow in dt.Rows)
                {
                    int Event_Id = Convert.ToInt32(dtRow[8].ToString());
                    string Details = "Present";
                    string Event_Name = "Attendance";
                    int Cls_Id = Convert.ToInt32(dtRow[1].ToString());
                    int Div_Id = Convert.ToInt32(dtRow[2].ToString());
                    int Std_Id = Convert.ToInt32(dtRow[0].ToString());
                    int Parent_Id = Convert.ToInt32(dtRow[6].ToString());

                    int User_Id = Convert.ToInt32(dtRow[6].ToString());
                    string Reg_Id = dtRow[5].ToString();
                    string studentname = dtRow[9].ToString();
                    string DateNow = dtRow[10].ToString();

                    con.Open();
                    SqlCommand CMDI = new SqlCommand("insert into RFID_Prenotification (std_id) values ('"+ Std_Id + "')", con);
                    CMDI.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                    var applicationID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";  // applicationID means google Api key 
                    var SENDER_ID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; // SENDER_ID is nothing but your ProjectID (from API Console- google code) 

                    var value = "RELAX! " + "" + studentname + "" + " marked as PRESENT for the day.";

                    //DateTime crnttime = DateTime.Now;
                    //TimeZoneInfo tzn = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time");
                    //DateTime IndianTme = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(crnttime, tzn);
                    //string Datee = IndianTme.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
                    //lbldate.Text = Date;

                    //DateTime crnttime1 = DateTime.Now;
                    //TimeZoneInfo tzn1 = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time");
                    //DateTime IndianTme1 = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(crnttime1, tzn1);
                    //string Date = IndianTme1.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
                    //lbldatee.Text = Date;

                    WebRequest tRequest;

                    tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
                    tRequest.Method = "post";
                    tRequest.ContentType = " application/json";
                    tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", applicationID));
                    tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", SENDER_ID));
                    string postData = "{\"collapse_key\":\"score_update\",\"time_to_live\":345600,\"delay_while_idle\":true,\"data\": { \"message\" : " + "\"" + value + "\",\"Event_Id\" : " + "\"" + Event_Id + "\",\"Details\" : " + "\"" + Details + "\",\"From_Date\" : " + "\"" + DateNow + "\",\"To_Date\" : " + "\"" + DateNow + "\",\"Event_Name\" : " + "\"" + Event_Name + "\",\"Cls_Id\" : " + "\"" +  Cls_Id + "\",\"Div_Id\" : " + "\"" + Div_Id + "\",\"Std_Id\" : " + "\"" + Std_Id + "\",\"Parent_Id\" : " + "\"" + Parent_Id + "\",\"time\": " + "\"" + DateNow + "\"},\"registration_ids\":[\"" + Reg_Id + "\"]}";
                    Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
                    tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
                    Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream();
                    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                    dataStream.Close();
                    WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse();
                    dataStream = tResponse.GetResponseStream();
                    StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                    String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();   //Get response from GCM server.                       
                    tReader.Close();
                    dataStream.Close();
                    tResponse.Close();

                    Alt_AutoIncreament_ID();
                    Objalrt.Action = "InserNotification1";
                    Objalrt.StrName = "SP_Set_App_Alert";
                    Objalrt.Alt_Id = Convert.ToInt32(Alt_Increment_Id).ToString();
                    Objalrt.User_Id = Convert.ToInt32(User_Id).ToString();
                    Objalrt.Std_Id = Convert.ToInt32(Std_Id).ToString();
                    Objalrt.Alt_Desc = value;
                    Objalrt.User_GCM_Reg_Id = "Default";
                    Objalrt.Log_Date = Convert.ToDateTime(DateNow);
                    int Count = Set_App_Alert_DataLayer.setdata(Objalrt);

                    Reg_Id = null;
                }
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.ArgumentException argEx = new System.ArgumentException("Index is out of range", "index", ex);
            throw argEx;
        }
    }`
```

Comment: Please publish the code or example you are working with

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com)! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. I suggest reading [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Also, be sure to take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Could you provide the related code snippets and expound why you say it's not working in Prod? Are you receiving any errors?

Comment: Atttached working code on localhost IIS with every datetime format. and manupulation in code. but after uploading only the sending part not working

Comment: class file contains this method. cant able to catch the error part, any error tracking mechanism will be helpful